# ES6 modules in chrome: ERR_ABORTED 404 (not found)

Tags: node.js, browser, ecmascript-6, module

I am making an ultra simplistic site using the new-ish module tags inside the html file I serve from node. I have the latest version of chrome.

My node js function: (appController)

```js
exports.getMainPage = (req, res) => {
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-type': 'text/html'});
    fs.readFile('./public/views/index.html', null, (err, data) => {
       if (err) console.error(err);
       else res.write(data);
       res.end();
    });
};
```

I'm using express:

```js
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const appController = require('../appController');

router.get('/', appController.getMainPage);

module.exports = router;
```

The html file:

```html
<html lang="eng">
<head>
    <script type="module">
        import { $, $$ } from '../javascript/modules/bling';

    </script>
    <title>Logs</title>
</head>

<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Webstorm confirms that the path is fine but the console keeps showing:

GET http://localhost:7777/javascript/modules/bling net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

Comment: Is your file named `bling` or `bling.js`? You're probably just missing the extension from the filename.

Comment: @loganfsmyth yes this way it works but I keep getting this https://imgur.com/Kl5ce2f , its like ES6 doesnt work?

EDIT: nvm I forgot to put back type="module", I got another error, just looking into that real quick...

Comment: That was it @loganfsmyth, I'm so used to put this line without the extension in my projects I did not think of that, normally I use babel. Cheers!